# Moving hosts between VLANS

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I have a question regarding the ability for a server to move devices between different VLANs. For example, I have VLAN 1 at 192.168.0.0/24 and VLAN 2 at 192.168.1.0/24. if my IDS registers something wrong with a certain device in VLAN 1 I would like to move it to VLAN 2. Is there anything that could be done here?

For context, the VLANs are created using Faucet SDN.

Comment: What's the make model of the IDS?

Comment: IDS is customly made. Does it matter? As in - is it the responsibility of the IDS to move devices between networks?